# Is it possible to convert one paragraph style into another in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have a scanned document in libreoffice that has a lot of different paragraph styles. I'd like to merge those numerous styles into a few so that the layout is more managable. I know styles can be edited and deleted, but can they be merged or converted into other existing styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible on an "indirect" way. Just use the search & replace functionality, it allows for searching styles and replacing them by another style, too. To use it, first create or modify the styles you want to use in then final document. Then, replace the existing styles by their replacement style. In the serach&replace dialogue, you need to activate <kbd>More Options</kbd>, the you can activate the style search.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way that also works but is perhaps more work is to link each of the current paragraph styles to the target paragraph style and then delete them. This should cause all paragraphs with those styles to revert to the linked to style.

[image: Organizer tab of Paragraph Style dialog, showing the "Linked with" field]